# Isomophism between rings an two right ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, abstract-algebra

Let **I**, **J** two right ideals of a ring R such that **I**+**J** =**R**. 
Show thath the direct sum of **I** and **J** is isomorphic  to the direct sum of **R** and the intersection of **I** and **J**.

Can anyone please give me at least  a ring morphism to prove this via first isomorphism theorem or there is another way to prove or attack this problem. Thanks

Comment: There is a short exact sequence $I\cap J\to I\oplus J\to I+J$. Not sure what to do with it. If $R$ has no idempotents other than $0$ and $1$, then $R\oplus(I\cap J)$ will have a nonzero idempotent whereas $I\oplus J$ will not. Are you sure you aren't looking for an isomorphism of $R$-modules?

Comment: mmm ok, the morphism from $$  I\oplus J\to I+J $$ is f(x,y)= x-y but what about the other morphism ?? :p

Comment: They're $a\mapsto (a,-a)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ respectively.

Comment: Hey boyz!  I understood it to be an isomorphism of $R$-modules since the ideals are one-sided.  Dig?  A one-sided ideal $I$ is a *module* over $R$, $R/I$ is a right module, not a ring unless $I$ is two sided.  So, like I said, the context seems to me to tacitly imply *module*-ness.

Comment: Ah, yes. That makes sense. Thanks babe.

Comment: Well the original problem doesnt make an statement about being an isomophism of R-modules but im also thinking its not a ring isomorphism btw :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an s.e.s. $I\cap J\to I\oplus J\to I+J$ given by $a\mapsto(a,-a)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$.

We want to show this splits, i.e. find a map $I+J\to I\oplus J$ such that $I+J\to I\oplus J\to I+J$ is the identity. Write $1=i+j$ and identify $I+J$ with $R$. The map $R\to I\oplus J$ is $r\mapsto (ir,jr)$.

Thus, the right $R$-module isomorphism $(I\cap J)\oplus R\mapsto I\oplus J$ is $(a,r)\mapsto (a+ir,-a+jr)$.

Comment: Yeep, thanks !!

Comment: My sentiments exactly, +1!